# Machine learning books covering neural networks / cnn / GAN

Tags: neural-networks, references, conv-neural-network, gan

I'm not an expert in machine learning. Is there any textbook (with a decent amount of mathematical rigor) that cover the subjects neural network / convolutional neural network / GAN network?

I've the Mitchell - Machine Learning but it is a bit old and it doesn't cover CNN and GAN.

Even a list would be fine so I can check by myself which one is more suitable.

Comment: Just to be more specific, I'm already following online courses, but I don't like them and I really would prefer textbooks that I can read through.

Comment: I understand - there are a few books mentioned in the answers to that question. Please check if those address your requirements; if you need something different, you could edit your question to explain more about what you're after.

Comment: They seem to be a bit old, also most of the links seem to be lecture notes or similar. Maybe something which is more recent, which covers the three topics I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to look at:

[Deep Learning by Ian Goodfellow , Yoshua Bengio, Aaron Courville](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/)

Which covers Neural Network, CNN, Boltzmann Machines. I'm not sure if it covers also GANs.